# How can I improve my aim on Urban Terror?

Tags: urban-terror

I would love to be able to get better shots on Urban Terror (fun but frustrating game). My mouse is a wee bit slow it seems (bad surface, not so much bad mouse, though of course the mouse is wired and that causes problems).

When I shoot it sometimes seems like half my shots do no damage even if I'm standing right in front of the person and shooting them in the head (no joke).

When others shoot me, they sometimes are not even aiming correctly and can kill me with a single bullet from guns like the l300!

So, is there anything I can do to improve my aim?

Comment: I guess it's not a specific answer but whenever I see a question like this I get the urge to say, "Buy a mouse with hardware sensitivity built into it!" I guess that's not much help though :). Furthermore, since this is an online game,  what's your ping to the server? In reality when you are shooting someone in the head they could have moved away from you. If your ping is high and their ping is low it'll give you the illusion that you have registered a hit locally but the server will know that you haven't.

Comment: @IttyBrittyGirlGamer My ping is just fine, and I would buy such a mouse if I could afford it right now. However, I'm convinced there must be something to this game that I'm missing 
(other than the aimbots that 90% of users have). P.S. consider this, my ping is regularly 100-something, and some who have 200 have better results than me. Also, more than once I've shot people who were afk, and it take over 5 seconds to kill them (madness!) while when I'm shot, on the move, and barely being aimed at, it sometimes takes 1 bullet (I often check the percentages) and the person gets a headshot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I aim better/kill people more often in first person shooters?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21817/how-can-i-aim-better-kill-people-more-often-in-first-person-shooters)

Answer (score 4):

**Practice, practice, practice**... use slow sensitivity and keep trying.

More hours playing against better players than you (easy way to see it's true: you kill nothing and dead always). Try playing 1vs1 against stronger players. Try to play clan wars with some friends. If your rival is better than you, even better for you.

Something to get into account is, more than hit the others, is not beeing hit. 
Here the key is: **position, position, cover**. Learn to have always a cover with you.
And learn to dodge the other's shots (moving left and right while shooting).

Maybe it seems too hard to be just a game, and I don't know how much time you've been playing this, but think that usually the "pros" have been playing for more than 5 years.

Good luck & have fun :D

Comment: Actually I stopped playing because I came to realize that a lot of the "good" players are cheating. Yes, there are skilled players in UT and every game, but like Tremulous and many other Q2/Q3 based games - the "pros" are often just cheaters and hackers. Lame, but true. It also got annoying when administrators knew this and ignored it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to shoot two or three shots at time, don't keep your finger on the mouse.  Use the dot crosshair, don't run while you are shooting, and aim to the head.

Comment: I've tried all of these. I think there is something more to this game. For example, I'm a relatively good sniper, and I know my response time could be better, but some people I have seen are able to fire bullets with the sr-8 while they are still moving! I don't get it.

Answer (score 1):

change the fire mode by pressing "n" ... you either can shoot onc shot, a couple of shots in sequence or your whole magazine. one shot is the most accurate while the autofire which empties your whole magazine is way to accurate....you can directly point at your enemy but most often will not hit him once.

Comment: been there done that ;)

but you get an up vote for trying.