# How can I improve my aim in Smite?

Tags: pc, smite, moba

This question is similar to [How can I aim better/kill people more often in first person shooters?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21817/how-can-i-aim-better-kill-people-more-often-in-first-person-shooters); but instead of first person shooters, I'm playing [Smite](http://www.smitegame.com/).

I find that when trying to aim skills that require skill shots, I tend to miss quite often, especially in the heat of battle. Cone shaped skills are much easier, but the line shaped skills always give me trouble.

Does getting better at aiming just come with practice, or is there something I can do to improve my aim?

Comment: Play FPSes'. (That's literally it, if you're talking about third-person games like Smite, which is a TPS and MOBA)

Comment: @aytimothy how will playing a FPS help with playing a TPS? wouldn't playing a TPS be better, wouldn't playing smite be better practice for smite?

Comment: Lower your mouse sensitivity, turn off mouse acceleration (unless you're very used to it), and then stick with it until you find something that works.

Comment: @Aequitas FPS are mostly faster and require even more reactions. If you are used to FPS, 'aiming' in TPS comes naturally - so my opinion.

Comment: The MOBA you are playing kinda affects it a lot actually. Smite is Third-Person, most MOBAs are top-down/Isometric like an RTS.

Comment: Can someone explain why this question is too broad please? It's the same question as the one I linked, except for MOBA instead of FPS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, the only way to get good at landing skillshots on enemy players is by practicing landing skillshots on enemy players.

The best way to do this is arena. You'll get good at skillshots and teamfights quickly.

That being said, since you're somewhat new, I recommend just playing Conquest (or Siege) and letting the learning and muscle memory come on its own. Arena is great for getting good at the combat quickly, but it will build bad habits for laning game-types.

Trust me from experience: those bad habits are very difficult to unlearn.

Comment: Great answer. There is also a "ruler" you can use from the settings menu which extends a 70 unit line straight out from your character

Comment: Since I play Assault so often, my 3v3 Joust/Seige/Conquest suffers pretty significantly. So I can definitely confirm that the gimicky maps leads to degradation of other skills necessary for the more mainstream maps.

Answer (score 1):

Play more FPS as aytimothy have advised.

Why?

Because every bullet you fire in a FPS is equivalent to said skill shot that you are having difficulty.  An FPS will be an ultra concentrated version of TPS MOBA skill shots that you need to get better at.