# If i Practice aiming with a bad mouse will it make me better with a good gaming mouse?

Tags: mouse, first-person-shooter

I am using this mouse i got from my old windows seven computer for my laptop and i have been using certain sites to practice my aiming for a few months now.
i was wondering if practicing with the mouse would make me better or worse with better mice such as the Razer DeathAdder Chroma Mouse and the Logitech G900 Chaos Spectrum.

Comment: This depends entirely on personal muscle memory, how each mouse functions, and your ability to adapt.  It's far too personal to be able to answer.

Comment: Adding on to Frank's response, the change in aiming will not differ much. In CSGO, I switched from a $10 wireless laser mouse to a Logitech G502 with no perceivable difference. Practicing in general will making you better, not your equipment.

Comment: Actually it is possible to give a valid answer: No, it won't. It's all about technical details.

Comment: Practicing with a crappy mouse is not on [the list](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/21817/how-can-i-aim-better-kill-people-more-often-in-first-person-shooters).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The price of the mouse does not have anything to do with that.
It depends on several factors, where a cheap mouse can be as good as an expensive one.

The factors are:

- Surface quality
- DPI
- Laser/optical
- Drag resistance
- You

The DPI is the most important setting. A new DPI setting will always need some getting used to. So if you want to practice a new setting, start with DPI.

Also a new mouse will most likely glide a lot better than your old one making it somewhat different to aim, even with the same DPI. That would be a good time to buy a new mouse surface, if you planned to do so in the near future anyway. (If not, clean it!)
That said, the drag resistance will be a lot less than before, which again needs some getting used to. - But it's worth it.

The final factor is yourself: How fast you can adapt to a new mouse and how comfortable you feel. It's unpredictable, how using different mouses will improve your personal skills. Technically it shouldn't make a difference.

TL;DR:
If you buy a new mouse and keep using the same DPI it will be only a short time to get used to it, but it will not improve your aim using an old mouse and then switching to a better one. Just switch right away, if you planned to do so.